# Concatenate array elements in order PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Is it possible to concatenate elements of 2 arrays in the correct order of its elements?

Example:

```
array1=['a','b','c']
array2=['d','e','f']

concatenated_array=['ad','be','cf']
```

My data is in the following way:

```
id           col1              col2
1        ['a','b','c']     ['d','e','f']
2        ['g','h','i']     ['j','k','l']
3        ['a','b','c']     ['j','k','l']
```

Comment: Just a hint: `select coalesce(x||y,x,y) from  unnest('{1,null,3}'::varchar[], '{a,b}'::varchar[]) t(x,y);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) and [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html) (with [column alias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)).

```
SELECT array_agg(el1||el2)
FROM unnest(ARRAY['a','b','c'], ARRAY['d','e','f']) el (el1, el2);

 array_agg  
------------
 {ad,be,cf}
(1 row)
```